# evaluate an expression which is the arithmetic mean of first $N$ partial sums of a geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to evaluate an expression which is the arithmetic mean of first $N$ partial sums of a geometric progression.It is given as below.

$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}(N-k)z^k$

Please suggest me some hints or ideas to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, you can evaluate

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}P(k)z^k$$

for any polynomial $P$ by using

$$(z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d z}) z^k=kz^k\;.$$

Thus, you can replace $k$ by $D:=z\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d z}$ in $P\,$:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(N-k)z^k
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{N}\right)z^k
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(1-\frac{D}{N}\right)z^k
\\
&=&
\left(1-\frac{D}{N}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}z^k
\\
&=&
\left(1-\frac{D}{N}\right)\frac{z^N-1}{z-1}\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$